# Heroku only displaying backend of MERN app. How can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, parceljs

I've finished working on my first MERN app. It works locally and it was 'successfully built' on Heroku but all that is displayed is the backend-data retrieved for the '/' route from MongoDB.

I've looked at a couple of resources that discuss deploying MERN stack apps to Heroku here:
1. https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/solved-deployment-problem-showing-backend/280178
2. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250/

I've tried integrating these posts with my code but to no avail. I'm not sure how to use the path middleware in tandem with my three existing routes ('/', '/authors', and '/books') and ultimately how that results in the build for index.html. I'm not sure if it makes any difference but I'm using parceljs to build the frontend.

[Edit: Added screenshot of folder layout to show where dist folder is located within the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9VIQ.png)

Below is my server.js file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  require("dotenv").config();
}

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

// Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "10mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "10mb" }));
app.use(cors());

// Connect to Mongoose
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", err => console.error(err));
db.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to Mongoose"));

// Define routes
const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
const authorRouter = require("./routes/authors");
const bookRouter = require("./routes/books");

// Utilize routes
app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/authors", authorRouter);
app.use("/books", bookRouter);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: Where do you create your public distribution folder? if you used create-react-app, when you run npm run build it will create a folder named dist and you should be able to serve it with your express application

Comment: Within my 'client' folder I have a 'dist' folder. Here is a screenshot of the overall layout of the project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9VIQ.png

With that being said, based on what I'm understanding from your response and the posts I read earlier, would the following be sufficient to include in my server.js file?

````app.get('*', (req, res) => {

      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist', 

    'index.html'));
    });
````

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code, if your app is in production express will serve static assets and it will redirect user to index.html if user comes to routes other than api routes(by providing app.get('*', ...))

***server.js***

```js
...

app.use("/books", bookRouter);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist')))
  app.get('*', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist', 'index.html'))
  })
}
```

Comment: I've added the code to server.js and re-deployed to Heroku but my app is still only displaying the backend. So, it didn't work. Thank you for trying to help me with the code though and by explaining the way serving the pages works

Comment: Can you try removing if statement to make sure the code runs in every environment?

Comment: I've removed the if statement. I've tried (separately) using a relative path for the app.use(express.static) line. I've also tried ˚˚˚˚(__dirname+ '/client/dist/' + 'index.html')˚˚˚˚ for the res.sendFile line (also, on a separate occasion)