# Heroku MERN application dosen't renders the template on initial render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, devops, mern

I am new to coding, completed developing sample MERN app, app is up and running on Heroku, but on first load only my data is rendered but the template is not rendered.

In my home page instead of JSX it only shows JSON data from backend, but when I manually change the URL to other pages it renders fine.

I already referred to [Heroku only displaying backend of MERN app. How can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073109/heroku-only-displaying-backend-of-mern-app-how-can-i-fix-this) but none of the answer seems to be working.

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: please share your code or share example code then only one can tell you what's wrong and give suggestion to fix it

Comment: My solution is not related to your question but my suggestion is to upload your server(backend) on Heroku and try deploying the client part in Netlify

Comment: Thank you for your reply it worked I deployed my server in heroku and frontend in netlify